# Difference between IIS and Share Point server

Tags: .net, sharepoint, iis

Can anyone explain me properly what is the actual difference between IIS6.0 and SharePoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: IIS is a web server, SharePoint is an application (web application + a set of services) that's hosted in IIS.

SharePoint is used for a LOT more than just document management - it's used for integrating data from back end systems, business process workflows, enterprise search...it's capabilities are pretty much a laundry list.

Comment: Could I add a bit of person opinion, that SharePoint can be extended to do anything, much like Word or Excel or Notepad+batch scripts: it can integrate data, perform searches but implementing all of those require buying something to do that or additional development.  It's not a holy grail but a choice of platform - nice in some ways because of the framework it provides but for most solutions, it's not the solution.  Unless it's out-of-the-box or a slight modification to SharePoint, it's good to consider developing from scratch or with a more suitable framework.

Comment: @Kieren excellent comment. So at its heart is it a CMS. It seems like there so much talk about what you _Can do_ not sure what Sharepoint is, which is making it difficult for me to choose which version to download.

Comment: Yes indeed, take my comment with a pinch of salt though.  I hate SharePoint.  I have dealt with many companies who implemented it without thinking or see it as an alternative to 'real' products.  "Document management?  Use SharePoint!" .. "Media (image/video) management?  Use SharePoint!".  Etc.   To me it's barely one step up from a network share with some Excel files on.  Implemented correctly it might be OK, but then, you better have a good reason for using it rather than something entirely bespoke.  (IMO)

Comment: @giddy - it's not at it's heart a CMS. That's one of the MANY, many many capabilities it has.

Comment: @kieren - not really. SharePoint has an extensive set of capabilities and integration points. What Microsoft brings to the table is basically a core set of functionality which can be extended or outright replaced in some cases by third party products. I would not so humbly disagree that building something from scratch is a good idea if you need anything approximating what SharePoint does. It's a pretty easy buy vs. build decision when SP brings the core capabilities to the table.

Comment: SharePoint is horrendously difficult to develop for (that's probably one reason good SP consultants are making so much money, it takes over 2 years just to become productive on the platform.)  I'd argue that 90%+ of the applications that businesses need will NOT require the overhead brought in by SharePoint (Full Disclosure: SharePoint Developer for 6 years)

Answer (score 2):

One is a webserver capable of hosting web pages and web applications (IIS).  The other (Sharepoint) is usually used for content management or document management systems, and sharing documents/information in (usually small-to-medium) companies.

Comment: Sharepoint sits ON top of IIS right?

Comment: Correct - SharePoint is hosted in IIS.